# Maintaining state between pages in seam

Tags: jsf, seam

I have a xhtml page with Search criteria and search results. Clicking on search button will dynamically update the results on the same page. I have a controller for search/results xhtml in Page Scope.

There is an edit button in every record in the search results. Clicking on the edit button will open a new page(new controller in Page scope). Once I edit and save I want to come back to the search criteria page with search resutls.

I can store the search criteria in session and requery and display the results. I looked at conversation and I am not sure if I can use it in this scenario?

Any ideas other than dumping the data in session for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the search criteria to the edit view as well (but don't display them or something) and then let the edit view pass it back to the search view once editing is finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data between two pages, you have many ways:

1) String parameters
2) Session data
3) Long running Conversation
4) Serialize your data elsewhere (DB or other).

Since you are talking about "saving" I may think you are saving your data in a database. If you have persisted your data in the second page in some way you can just query for them.

Otherwise you can use session and conversation, the second has a "smaller" and defined scope. You can decide when to create one and to create destroy. Simply put a  in the first page pages.xml and create a bean with conversation scope.

The session scope will keep your data in your session scoped component until you close your browser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the session scoped bean.  If you use a search bean you can go anywhere in your application and maintain your search state, also it lends itself to saving searches in the database (so users can save searches between sessions).

```
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("someRandomSearch") 
public class SomeRandomSearch {    
    private SearchObj1 userSelection1;
    private List<SearchObj1> searchCriteriaList1;
    private SearchObj2 userSelection2;
    private List<SearchObj2> searchCriteriaList2;
    private String randomUserInput;
    // getters/setters, some helper classes, cascade dropdown stuff, etc.....

    // clear search criteria
    public void reset(){
         this.userSelection1 = null;
         this.userSelection2 = null;
         this.randomUserInput = null;
    }
}
```

Just make sure to implement equals method in your model classes - maybe that's obvious, but when I first started using Seam I missed this little tidbit and it took forever to figure out why we couldn't hold onto dropdown selections in our search pages.

Comment: If you have 2 search pages open in 2 different browser windows/tabs within the same session and make actions on both, everything will behave unintuitive this way, because the data of the one overwrites the other (and vice versa). Better stick to request, view or conversation scope.

Comment: BalusC, what do you do to maintain state across conversations?

Comment: As said, use request, view or conversation scope.

Comment: I have an app with several search pages, a user can edit from search pages or go to other search pages, we have to maintain search criteria across the entire application for all those searches.  How would you do that using conversation or page scope?

Answer (score 0):

If when you say "open a new page", you mean navigate to another page in the same browser window/tab, then a `Conversation` is the ideal method for storing the search state.

Depending on your detailed use case, you might prefer to setup nested conversations (when you click on the edit).

You might also want to setup a pageflow to manage that particular navigation logic.

See [the official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e3620).